# File validation using javascript in IE 8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate file size using javascript validation. it is working fine for other browsers but not working for Internet Explorer
Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see the code? Try setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Can you show us your working code? Any errors it throws?

Comment: i have fiddle my code on the following link please check.
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/faisalshehzad/hBjaf/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript it is not possible to get file object in IE and safari. You can use jquery plugin uploadify that work fine for all browsers. Have many options to check file size, type etc. 
To save values of files like name, size or whatever, you can use uplodify return response. Save these values in hidden fields and on post save them in your DB.

Please visit the following link. http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/